# How to unscribe from a subscription using a condition in angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do I unsubscribe to a subscription with a condition in typescript.

I subscribed to a $http.get method in Angular4, now I want to unsubscribe after received "no_more_data" from the server. Please let me know how to do it.

All the methods that I know like takeuntil, takewhile etc are not available on this Observable

```
getFiles(): any {
    return http.post
}

getFiles(). // here no takeWhile and takeUntil are getring allowed then how do I unsubscribe.
```

Comment: Can you show what exactly you have tried till now?

Comment: What is `$http.get`? Are you using AngularJS? Your question is marked Angular though.

Comment: Sorry I recently started using Angular 4 after Angular 1 so mistakenly typed $http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're a few things here:

First, the observable that comes from Http in Angular makes a single Http request, so, no need to unsubscribe if it's just a single Http call, unless you are triggering it from something else that is repeated of course.

Second, the part that you mention, `return http.post` is obviously incomplete. I don't know whether this is just for posting in the question or your real code is like that. Your problem might be that you are returning the function `http.post` instead of calling it.

Check if your real code 1) calls the method `http.post( /*some arguments here /*)`, and of course 2) does return the result of that call. Hover over your method that calls `http.post()` to ensure the return type is an `Observable`.

Finally, another potential small gotcha if you are unable to find the `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` still, is that it might simply be not imported. You might need to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile` or `'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil`` to the beginning of the file that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `takeWhile` operator to make the stream close automatically when `"no_more_data"` arrives:

```
$http.get(...)
.map(...)
.takeWhile((e) => e != "no_more_data")
.subscribe(...)
```

See also [takeWhile](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ae9b17fdc93d84bd235c0d2c53afa09f1867a3f8/src/operators/takeWhile.ts)